# add addtional summary row in smartgwt Grid

Tags: grid, smartgwt

Im trying to add a summary row which sum all values in each column. I have very large data and I do pagination in the grid. However, I heard gwt doing summaryGrid in client side which does not work in my case. I tried to setShowGridSummary to true but it works only for a small set of data, it shows blank if the data is large. So I want to change the plan to add additional summary grid and then get the query from backend and insert the summary data into that grid. So my question is can I add additional row into smartgwt grid? And how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On client side SmartGWT can only calculate summary if you fetched all records so only then summary values will show.
You can disable pagination and do this which I don't recommend for large data sets. Or prepare another data source that can calculate summary on server side and return only one record:

> listGrid.setSummaryRowDataSource(summaryRowDataSource);

SmartGWT will make another request to server for summary row with same criteria that was used for normal fetch.
It will be also refetched any time criteria will change.